# Closures in PHP... what, precisely, are they and when would you need to use them?

Tags: php, oop, closures

So I'm programming along in a nice, up to date, object oriented fashion. I regularly make use of the various aspects of OOP that PHP implements but I am wondering when might I need to use closures. Any experts out there that can shed some light on when it would be useful to implement closures?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

PHP will support closures natively in 5.3.  A closure is good when you want a local function that's only used for some small, specific purpose.  The [RFC for closures](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures) gives a good example:

```
function replace_spaces ($text) {
    $replacement = function ($matches) {
        return str_replace ($matches[1], ' ', '&nbsp;').' ';
    };
    return preg_replace_callback ('/( +) /', $replacement, $text);
}
```

This lets you define the `replacement` function locally inside `replace_spaces()`, so that it's not:
**1)** cluttering up the global namespace
**2)** making people three years down the line wonder why there's a function defined globally that's only used inside one other function

It keeps things organized. Notice how the function itself has no name, it's simply defined and assigned as a reference to `$replacement`.

But remember, you have to wait for PHP 5.3 :)

Comment: This is an awesome explanation. +1

Comment: I enjoyed the explanation of **why** you would use closures. Most people don't really grasp that. +1

Comment: This is an explanation of anonymous functions, not an explanation of closures. Anonymous functions are, as you say, just like named functions except they're not global. Closures, on the other hand, are functions containing lexically-scoped free variables (declared with "use"); ie. they can copy and reference values from the scope they're declared in, even after everything else has been garbage collected.

Comment: @Warbo This is true; at the time I didn't really grok the difference between an anonymous function and a closure. Closures really only make sense once you grok anonymous functions, but _to this day_ I still find "explanations" of what a closure is (like mine, from 7 years ago ;-) ) that don't explain the scope aspect of it.

Comment: That's why I was saying, check out JavaScript where closures are heavily used - but keep in mind that variable scope rules are different in PHP.

Answer (score 17):

When you will need a function in the future which performs a task that you have decided upon now.

For example, if you read a config file and one of the parameters tells you that the `hash_method` for your algorithm is `multiply` rather than `square`, you can create a closure that will be used wherever you need to hash something.

The closure can be created in (for example) `config_parser()`; it creates a function called `do_hash_method()` using variables local to `config_parser()` (from the config file). Whenever `do_hash_method()` is called, it has access to variables in the local scope of`config_parser()` even though it's not being called in that scope.

A hopefully good hypothetical example:

```
function config_parser()
{
    // Do some code here
    // $hash_method is in config_parser() local scope
    $hash_method = 'multiply';

    if ($hashing_enabled)
    {
        function do_hash_method($var)
        {
            // $hash_method is from the parent's local scope
            if ($hash_method == 'multiply')
                return $var * $var;
            else
                return $var ^ $var;
        }
    }
}


function hashme($val)
{
    // do_hash_method still knows about $hash_method
    // even though it's not in the local scope anymore
    $val = do_hash_method($val)
}
```

Comment: I cannot simply copy paste this example and run it. Preferred an example that I can simply run.

Comment: This answer is poor. This is a meaningless statement: "When you will need a function in the future which performs a task that you have decided upon now."

Answer (score 17):

Apart from the technical details, closures are a fundamental pre-requisite for a programming style known as function oriented programming. A closure is roughly used for the same thing as you use an object for in object oriented programming; It binds data (variables) together with some code (a function), that you can then pass around to somewhere else. As such, they impact on the way that you write programs or - if you don't change the way you write your programs - they don't have any impact at all.

In the context of PHP, they are a little odd, since PHP already is heavy on the class based, object oriented paradigm, as well as the older procedural one. Usually, languages that have closures, has full lexical scope. To maintain backwards compatibility, PHP is not going to get this, so that means that closures are going to be a little different here, than in other languages. I think we have yet to see exactly how they will be used.

Answer (score 10):

I like the context provided by troelskn's post. When I want to do something like Dan Udey's example in PHP, i use the OO Strategy Pattern. In my opinion, this is much better than introducing a new global function whose behavior is determined at runtime.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern

You can also call functions and methods using a variable holding the method name in PHP, which is great. so another take on Dan's example would be something like this:

```
class ConfigurableEncoder{
        private $algorithm = 'multiply';  //default is multiply

        public function encode($x){
                return call_user_func(array($this,$this->algorithm),$x);
        }

        public function multiply($x){
                return $x * 5;
        }

        public function add($x){
                return $x + 5;
        }

        public function setAlgorithm($algName){
                switch(strtolower($algName)){
                        case 'add':
                                $this->algorithm = 'add';
                                break;
                        case 'multiply':        //fall through
                        default:                //default is multiply
                                $this->algorithm = 'multiply';
                                break;
                }
        }
}

$raw = 5;
$encoder = new ConfigurableEncoder();                           // set to multiply
echo "raw: $raw\n";                                             // 5
echo "multiply: " . $encoder->encode($raw) . "\n";              // 25
$encoder->setAlgorithm('add');
echo "add: " . $encoder->encode($raw) . "\n";                   // 10
```

of course, if you want it to be available everywhere, you could just make everything static...

Answer (score 2):

A closure is basically a function for which you write the definition in one context but run in another context. Javascript helped me a lot with understanding these, because they are used in JavaScript all over the place.

In PHP, they are less effective than in JavaScript, due to differences in the scope and accessibility of "global" (or "external") variables from within functions. Yet, starting with PHP 5.4, closures can access the $this object when run inside an object, this makes them a lot more effective.

This is what closures are about, and it should be enough to understand what is written above.

This means that it should be possible to write a function definition somewhere, and use the $this variable inside the function definition, then assign the function definition to a variable (others have given examples of the syntax), then pass this variable to an object and call it in the object context, the function can then access and manipulate the object through $this as if it was just another one of it's methods, when in fact it's not defined in the class definition of that object, but somewhere else.

If it's not very clear, then don't worry, it will become clear once you start using them.

Comment: Honestly, I this is not clear at all, even for me, the author.
Basically I'm saying: to learn what closures are check them out in JavaScript, but keep in mind that variable scope is different between JavaScript and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Here are examples for closures in php**

```
// Author: HishamDalal@gamil.com
// Publish on: 2017-08-28

class users
{
    private $users = null;
    private $i = 5;

    function __construct(){
        // Get users from database
        $this->users = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f');
    }

    function displayUsers($callback){
        for($n=0; $n<=$this->i; $n++){
            echo  $callback($this->users[$n], $n);
        }
    }

    function showUsers($callback){
        return $callback($this->users);

    }

    function getUserByID($id, $callback){
        $user = isset($this->users[$id]) ? $this->users[$id] : null;
        return $callback($user);
    }

}

$u = new users();

$u->displayUsers(function($username, $userID){
    echo "$userID -> $username<br>";
});

$u->showUsers(function($users){
    foreach($users as $user){
        echo strtoupper($user).' ';
    }

});

$x = $u->getUserByID(2, function($user){

    return "<h1>$user</h1>";
});

echo ($x);
```

**Output:**

```
0 -> a
1 -> b
2 -> c
3 -> d
4 -> e
5 -> f

A B C D E F 

c
```

Answer (score 1):

Bascially,Closure are the inner functions tat have access to the outer variables and are used as a callback function to anonmyous function (functions that do not have any name).

```
 <?php
      $param='ironman';
      function sayhello(){
          $param='captain';
          $func=function () use ($param){
                $param='spiderman';
          };
       $func();
       echo  $param;
       }
      sayhello();
?>

//output captain

//and if we pass variable as a reference as(&$param) then output would be spider man;
```

Comment: `$param='captain'` in func `sayhello()` is local variable to func `sayhello()`.
`$param='ironman'` above `sayhello()` is global variable. If you want to make only one $param variable in your script you should call:
`global $param;`
within `sayhello()` func

Answer (score 1):

**Closures:**

MDN has the best explanation IMO:

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed)
> with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In
> other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope
> from an inner function.

i.e. A closure is a function with access to the variables which are in the parent scope. A closure allows us to conveniently create functions on the fly since in some situations a functions is only needed in one place (callbacks, callable arguments).

**Example:**

```
$arr = [1,2,3,3];
$outersScopeNr = 2;

// The second arg in array_filter is a closure
// It would be inconvenient to have this function in global namespace
// The use keyword lets us access a variable in an outer scope
$newArr = array_filter($arr, function ($el) use ($outersScopeNr) {
    return $el === 3 || $el === $outersScopeNr;
});

var_dump($newArr);
// array (size=3)
//  1 => int 2
//  2 => int 3
//  3 => int 3
```