# Calling closure assigned to object property directly

Tags: php, object, properties, closures

I would like to be able to call a closure that I assign to an object's property directly without reassigning the closure to a variable and then calling it. Is this possible?

The code below doesn't work and causes `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::callback()`.

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->callback = function() {
    print "HelloWorld!";
};
$obj->callback();
```

Comment: This is exactly what you need: https://github.com/ptrofimov/jslikeobject Even more: you can use $this inside closures and use inheritance. Only PHP>=5.4!

Answer (score 128, accepted):

As of PHP7, you can do

```
$obj = new StdClass;
$obj->fn = function($arg) { return "Hello $arg"; };
echo ($obj->fn)('World');
```

or use [Closure::call()](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php), though that doesn't work on a `StdClass`.

---

Before PHP7, you'd have to implement the magic `__call` method to intercept the call and invoke the callback (which is not possible for `StdClass` of course, because you cannot add the `__call` method)

```
class Foo
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if(is_callable(array($this, $method))) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
        }
        // else throw exception
    }
}

$foo = new Foo;
$foo->cb = function($who) { return "Hello $who"; };
echo $foo->cb('World');
```

Note that you cannot do

```
return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $args);
```

in the `__call` body, because this would trigger `__call` in an infinite loop.

Comment: Sometimes you will find this syntax usefull - 
call_user_func_array($this->$property, $args); 
when it is about callable class property, not a method.

Answer (score 112):

You can do this by calling __invoke on the closure, since that's the magic method that objects use to behave like functions:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->callback = function() {
    print "HelloWorld!";
};
$obj->callback->__invoke();
```

Of course that won't work if the callback is an array or a string (which can also be valid callbacks in PHP) - just for closures and other objects with __invoke behavior.

Comment: @marcioAlmada very ugly though.

Comment: @Mahn I think it's more explicit than the accepted answer. Explicit is better in this case. If you really care for a "cute" solution, `call_user_func($obj->callback)` is not that bad.

Comment: But `call_user_func` works with strings too and that's not always convinient

Comment: @cerebriform semantically it makes no sense to have to do `$obj->callback->__invoke();` when one would expect it to be `$obj->callback()`. It's just a question of consistency.

Comment: @Mahn: Granted, it's not consistent.  Consistency has never really been PHP strong suit, though. :)  But I think it does makes sense, when one considers the object nature: `$obj->callback instanceof \Closure`.

Answer (score 29):

As of [**PHP 7**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) you can do the following:

```
($obj->callback)();
```

Comment: Such common sense, yet it's purely badass. The great power of PHP7!

Answer (score 11):

Since **[PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php)** a closure can be called using the [`call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.call.php) method:

```
$obj->callback->call($obj);
```

Since **[PHP 7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax)** is possible to execute operations on arbitrary `(...)` expressions too (as explained by [Korikulum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709567/1750243)):

```
($obj->callback)();
```

Other common **PHP 5** approaches are:

- using the magic method [`__invoke()`](http://php.net/manual/it/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) (as explained by [Brilliand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063179/1750243))

  ```
  $obj->callback->__invoke();
  ```
- using the [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) function

  ```
  call_user_func($obj->callback);
  ```
- using an *intermediate variable* in an expression

  ```
  ($_ = $obj->callback) && $_();
  ```

Each way has its own pros and cons, but the most radical and definitive solution  still remains the one presented by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535383/1750243).

```
class stdKlass
{
    public function __call($method, $arguments)
    {
        // is_callable([$this, $method])
        //   returns always true when __call() is defined.

        // is_callable($this->$method)
        //   triggers a "PHP Notice: Undefined property" in case of missing property.

        if (isset($this->$method) && is_callable($this->$method)) {
            return call_user_func($this->$method, ...$arguments);
        }

        // throw exception
    }
}

$obj = new stdKlass();
$obj->callback = function() { print "HelloWorld!"; };
$obj->callback();
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems to be possible using `call_user_func()`.

```
call_user_func($obj->callback);
```

not elegant, though.... What @Gordon says is probably the only way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Well, if you ***really*** insist. Another workaround would be:

```
$obj = new ArrayObject(array(),2);

$obj->callback = function() {
    print "HelloWorld!";
};

$obj['callback']();
```

But that's not the nicest syntax.

However, the PHP parser always treats `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR`, `IDENTIFIER`, `(` as method call. There seems to be no workaround for making `->` bypass the method table and access the attributes instead.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old, but I think Traits nicely handle this problem if you are using PHP 5.4+

First, create a trait that makes properties callable:

```
trait CallableProperty {
    public function __call($method, $args) {
        if (property_exists($this, $method) && is_callable($this->$method)) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can use that trait in your classes:

```
class CallableStdClass extends stdClass {
    use CallableProperty;
}
```

Now, you can define properties via anonymous functions and call them directly:

```
$foo = new CallableStdClass();
$foo->add = function ($a, $b) { return $a + $b; };
$foo->add(2, 2); // 4
```

Comment: Wow :) This is much more elegant than what I was trying to do.  My only question is the same as for british hot/cold tap connector elements: WHY is it not built in already??

Comment: Thanks :).  It's probably not built in because of the ambiguity it creates.  Imagine in my example, if there was actually a function called "add" and a property called "add".  The presence of the parenthesis tells PHP to look for a function with that name.

Answer (score 2):

well, it should be emphisized that storing the closure in a variable, and call the varible is actually (wierdly) faster, depending on the call amount, it becomes quite a lot, with xdebug (so very precise measuring), we are talking about 1,5 (the factor, by using a varible, instead of directly calling the __invoke. so instead , just store the closure in a varible and call it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another alternative based on the accepted answer but extending stdClass directly:

```
class stdClassExt extends stdClass {
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (isset($this->$method)) {
            $func = $this->$method;
            return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
$foo = new stdClassExt;
$foo->blub = 42;
$foo->whooho = function () { return 1; };
echo $foo->whooho();
```

You are probably better off using `call_user_func` or `__invoke` though.

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->callback = function() {
     print "HelloWorld!";
};
```

**PHP >= 7 :**

```
($obj->callback)();
```

**PHP >= 5.4 :**

```
$callback = $obj->callback;  
$callback();
```

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't work. `Call to undefined method AnyObject::callback()` (Class AnyObject exists, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP 5.4 or above you could bind a callable to the scope of your object to invoke custom behavior. So for example if you were to have the following set up..

```
function run_method($object, Closure $method)
{
    $prop = uniqid();
    $object->$prop = \Closure::bind($method, $object, $object);
    $object->$prop->__invoke();
    unset($object->$prop);
}
```

And you were operating on a class like so..

```
class Foo
{
    private $value;
    public function getValue()
    {
        return $this->value;
    }
}
```

You could run your own logic as if you were operating from within the scope of your object

```
$foo = new Foo();
run_method($foo, function(){
    $this->value = 'something else';
});

echo $foo->getValue(); // prints "something else"
```

Answer (score 0):

I note that this works in PHP5.5

```
$a = array();
$a['callback'] = function() {
    print "HelloWorld!";
};
$a['callback']();
```

Allows one to create a psuedo-object collection of closures.