# Creating a variable_function as member of a class

Tags: php, variables, dynamic

Let's say we have a class stockFns and I do

```
$stockFns->{$functionOne}=create_function('$a,$b' , 'return $a+$b;');
```

This creates a property in $stockFns named whatever create_function returned.

Now I want to refer (invoke) to the created_function.

What would be a clean way to do it in a single instruction?. An example

```
$stockFns=new StockFns;
$functionOne='add';
$stockFns->{$functionOne}=create_function('$a,$b' , 'return $a+$b;');

//echo "***" . ($stockFns->add)(1,2);  // That doesn't work
$theFn=$stockFns->add;
echo $theFn(1,2);         // This works but reuires two instructions
```

Thanks!

Comment: Forgot to menction, the name of the function is also a variable but I guess it doesn't matter in this problem.

Comment: Can you give some context as to why you need to do this rather than create a new class which extends `StockFns`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly)

Comment: drewm: Was thinking on possibilites on  somehow flexible way to translate strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your way, or

```
echo call_user_func(array($stockFbs, 'add'), 1, 2);
```

The problem is, that PHP cannot distinguish real methods from properties with callables. If you call something with `()` it will not touch the properties at all and in maybe will call `__call`, if it exists. You can try something like

```
class StockFns {
  public function __call ($name, $args) {
    $fctn = $this->{$name};
    return call_user_func_array($fctn, $args);
  }
}
```

As a workaround, so `__call()` will redirect to your callback.

Comment: see the linked duplicate as to why this may cause an infinite loop. you have to check if $name is callable.

Comment: thanks. now its almost the same answer as in the linked dup. *cough* close *cough* vote.

Comment: @Gordon: Ah, now I see, what you mean. I have omitted the checks, if everything is valid, to make it better readable. I think everybody should be able to find (at least the hard way ;)) the pitfalls and validate hisself.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried call_user_func?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

```
echo call_user_func(array($stockFns, $functionOne), 1, 2);
```

if you're using PHP5.3 and up, you should really consider using anonymous function

http://my.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Yes but I was searching something "clean" as the method would be called many times around the code. thanks!