# Anonymous function for a method of an object

Tags: php, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly)

Why this is not possible in PHP? I want to be able to create a function on the fly for a particular object.

```
$a = 'a';
$tokenMapper->tokenJoinHistories = function($a) {
   echo $a;
};
$tokenMapper->tokenJoinHistories($a);
```

Comment: What is the error you get from this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `$obj->foo()` you call methods, but you want to call a property *as* a function/method. This just confuses the parser, because he didn't find a method with the name `foo()`, but he cannot expect any property to be something callable.

```
call_user_func($tokenMapper->tokenJoinHistories, $a);
```

Or you extend your mapper like

```
class Bar {
  public function __call ($name, $args) {
    if (isset($this->$name) && is_callable($this->$name)) {
      return call_user_func_array($this->$name, $args);
    } else {
      throw new Exception("Undefined method '$name'");
    } 
  }
}
```

(There are probably some issues within this quickly written example)

Answer (score 2):

PHP tries to match an instance method called "tokenJoinHistories" that is not defined in the original class

You have to do instead

```
$anon_func = $tokenMapper->tokenJoinHistories;
$anon_func($a);
```

Read the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) especially the comment part.