# Adding a PHP anonymous function to an object

Tags: php, oop, closures, anonymous-function

Is it possible to add an anonymous function to an object, and call it within the object.  See below for example code.  [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly) and [Anonymous function for a method of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775774/anonymous-function-for-a-method-of-an-object) describe calling it directly, not within the object.  Thank you

```
class myClass
{
    public function go()
    {
        $this->scope;
    }
}

$myObj=new myClass();
$myObj->scope=function()
{
    echo('Print This!');
};
$myObj->go();
```

Comment: Not sure if it is but you need to define your property first

Comment: @php_nub_qq.  No effect when defining the property first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->scope` needs to called/executed within `myClass:go`. For example: -

```
<?php
class Example {
    protected
        $callback;

    public function setCallback($callback) {
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function invoke() {
        call_user_func($this->callback);
    }
}

$example = new Example;

$example->setCallback(function(){
    echo 'Hello World';
});

$example->invoke();
/*
    Hello World
*/
```

Anthony.

Comment: Thanks Anthony,  Seems call_user_func() is what I needed.