# Invoking a function from a class member in PHP

Tags: php, first-class-functions

Say I have the following:

```
class C {
    private $f;

    public function __construct($f) {
        $this->f = $f;
    }

    public function invoke ($n) {
        $this->f($n); // <= error thrown here
    }
}

$c = new C(function ($m) {
    echo $m;
});

$c->invoke("hello");
```

The above throws the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method C::f()

And I'm guessing that it's because I'm trying to invoke the callback function `$this->f` using the same syntax one would invoke an object's member functions.

So what's the syntax that allows you to invoke a function which is stored in a member variable?

Comment: Shot in the dark: `($this->f)($n)`.  If that doesn't work, try `$f = $this->f; $f($n);`.

Comment: +1 Oh, the latter worked!  But that seems like a strange way to do it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `call_user_func`:

```
public function invoke ($n) {
    call_user_func($this->f, $n);
}
```

### UPDATE

Christian points out that `call_user_func` is very slow, and that this is faster:

```
function my_call_user_func($f) {
    $f();
}
```

Comment: +1 Ah, this may be what I was looking for; it worked with `call_user_func`.

Comment: -1 Andreas, **don't use call_user_func()**, it is incredibly slow. This is even faster: `function my_call_user_func($f){ $f(); }`