# Closures don't work as class methods?

Tags: php, closures

Am I missing something or do closures simply not work as class methods? Take this for instance:

```
$foo = new stdClass();
$foo->bar = function() {
   echo '@@@';
};
$foo->bar();
```

Seems to give me an error of "Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::bar() in /blah/blah.php on line X"

Shouldn't this instead invoke the closure that was placed in the "bar" property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed correct.

The only way to call `bar` is:

```
$bar = $foo->bar;
$bar();
```

Sad, but true.

<strike>Also worth noting, because of this same effect, there is no `$this` inside $bar call (unless you pass it as function argument named as `$this`).</strike>

**Edit:** As [nikic](/questions/tagged/nikic) pointed out, the value of `$this` inside the closure is the same value of the scope of when the closure was created.
This may mean that `$this` might be undefined on two occasions: when the scope was the global PHP scope or when the scope was from a static context. This, however, means that you can in theory feed the correct instance:

```
class Foo {
    public $prop = 'hi';
    function test(){
        $this->bar = function(){
            echo $this->prop;
        }

        $bar = $this->bar;
        $bar();
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->test();
```

Also, it seems that with some class magic, you can achieve `$this->bar()` as well:

```
class Foo {
    // ... other stuff from above ...
    public function __call($name, $args){
        $closure = $this->$name;
        call_user_func_array( $closure, $args ); // *
    }
}
```

[*] Beware that `call_user_func_array` is **very** slow.

**Oh, and this is strictly for PHP 5.4 only. Before that, there's no `$this` in closures :)**

**Also**, you can see it in action [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/A2A6HY).

Comment: guh. is this going to be changed anytime soon?

Comment: $this in a closure gives me an error that it was used in a non object context even though it was defined within an object as well as called within an object.

Comment: Are you using PHP 5.4? Please do try my demonstration on viper7.

Comment: @dqhendricks you're out of luck then :/

Comment: It's also possible to call a closure class member using `->invoke()`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly/14063179#14063179

Answer (score 1):

Methods and fields are completely separate; in fact, you can even have a method and field of the same name:

```
<?php
class foo{
    function bar() { echo "hello\n"; }
}
$object = new foo;
$object->bar = 1;
$object->bar(); // echoes "hello"
?>
```

This explains why your syntax could not have created a "real" method.

Comment: I didn't expect it to create a "real" method, but I did expect it to let me invoke the closure within the property.

Comment: @dqhendricks: then there would be no syntactical difference between calling the method `bar` and calling the function stored in the field `bar`. So it would be ambiguous what you were doing

Comment: you are correct. this would cause confusion. this would have been a very useful feature in my particular case however, but i have found a way to implement the same functionality without it.