# PHP closure function appended to stdObject and chained

Tags: php, closures, chaining

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly)

If I have a class like this:

```
class test{
  function one(){
     $this->two()->func(); //Since $test is returned, why can I not call func()?
  }

  function two(){
    $test = (object) array();
    $test->func = function(){
       echo 'Does this work?';
    };
    return $test;
  }
}

$new = new test;
$new->one(); //Expecting 'Does this work?'
```

So my question is, when I call function two from function one, function two returns the $test variable which has a closure function of func() attached to it.  Why can I not call that as a chained method?

**Edit**
I just remembered that this can also be done by using $this->func->__invoke() for anyone that needs that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is currently a limitation of PHP. What you are doing is logical and should be possible. In fact, you can work around the limitation by writing:

```
function one(){
    call_user_func($this->two()->func);
}
```

or

```
function one(){
    $f = $this->two()->func;
    $f();
}
```

Stupid, I know.

Comment: Heh, interesting.  Thanks for the help.