# How do I define a function signature within a class (without actually defining the function body)

Tags: php, callback, delegates

What is the difference between these codes in PHP?

code1:

```
$func=function($name){
         return "name : ".$name;

};
echo $func('john');// << it is true
```

code2:

```
class myclass{
         public $name;
         public $func;

}
$c=new myclass();
$c->func=function($n){
         return "name : ".$n;
};
echo $c->func();// << ?!.. is error
```

The first code is working properly but the second code gives an error. How can I fix it?
Sidenote: My PHP version is 5.3.4

Comment: why does code2 looks like it was javascript

Comment: interesting answers to this in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that using [`Closures`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) in PHP.

```
<?php
class A {
    public $name;
    public $func;
}

$cl2 = function($n) {
     return "name : ".$n;
};


$func = Closure::bind($cl2, new A(), 'A');
echo $func('john');
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
name : john
```

Comment: My Php does not know this.

Comment: What is  so active?my php version 5.3.4

Comment: thanks,'Closure' not work for me. but i find from answer 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly'