# PHP Call closure under stdClass

Tags: php

This is what I have

```
$x = new \stdClass();
$x->cast = function($y){
    return $y;
};
```

and when I try to execute it

```
$x->cast(5);
```

I get this error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::cast()

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you `var_dump()` this variable does `cast` show as Closure?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk yes, it does

Comment: And I assume you have a semicolon after that function body? I see no errors in this code... Your PHP version is?

Comment: Well I see no errors as well. I'm using version 5.5.6

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly)

Comment: Sorry for closing, but linked question explains why. Never needed to do this, but worth knowing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general it's nicer to just make a class if you want to attach functions to objects
but in case you really want this then this should work:

```php
$x = new \stdClass();
$x->cast = function($y){
    return $y;
};

$y = $x->cast;

var_dump($y(5));
```

or

```
call_user_func($x->cast, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but can you tell me also why this is not working? I mean if I were to use an array instead of an object then I'd be able to call the function with `$x['cast'](5)`but with an object it's not working?

Comment: I don't know enough about php internals to give a really confident answer, but I believe it's just a matter of php not looking for properties that might be functions when you call a method on an object. Normally when you have a construction that looks like a function call php will try to interpret it as such in several different ways, proper function, string, array, etc, but I guess it's different with objects.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're defining a variable and assigning it a closure function inside your stdClass

If you want to understand why calling `$x->cast(5);` doesn't work it's because PHP is looking for a method of the class named 'cast' but there is no such *method* instead only a *property* named 'cast', properties and methods are two different things for PHP

So for what you want to achieve to work you need to call (PHP 7+ syntax only)

```php
($x->cast)(5);
```

Or for PHP 5.3+

```php
$x->cast->__invoke(5)
```

Or for any version

```php
call_user_func($x->cast, 5);
```

to tell the compiler that first you want to access the variable (which returns the closure) and then to call this closure with the parameter 5