# Strange Object/Class Issue (stdClass)

Tags: php

I've just recently began messing around with anonymous functions, and I decided to try and put it to actual use in a larger project. After hitting a road block, I tried setting up a small practice script, but the same issue persists. I don't quite understand what's going on, but here's some code,

```
$a = function($in) {
  echo $in;
};
$a('b4ng');
```

The above works just fine, as does the following,

```
class Foo {

    public $cmd;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->cmd = new stdClass();
        $this->cmd->a = 'b4ng';
    }
}

$bar = new Foo();
echo $bar->cmd->a;
```

That being made clear, the following does **not** work,

```
class Foo {

    public $cmd;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->cmd = new stdClass();
        $this->cmd->message = function($in) {

            echo $in;
        };
    }
}

$bar = new Foo();
$bar->cmd->message('b4ng');
```

When attempting to use the snippet above, I'm hit with the following error,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::message()
```

I understand what the error is telling me, I just don't understand why; 'message' obviously isn't a native function/method of stdClass, but it was declared in 'cmd'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling closure assigned to object property directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly) - `$bar->cmd->message->__invoke('b4ng');`

Comment: @FuzzyTree, thank you, my apologies for not looking around prior to posting this question. In any case, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

There is another thing you can't do:

```
$o = new SomeClass();
$m = $o->someMethod;
$m();
```

The issue here is that PHP has a special syntax for a member function call, which is what matches `$o->foo()`. In your case though, `foo` is a closure (i.e. a data member, not a method) so that causes the error. In order to fix this, you first need to retrieve `foo` from your object and then invoke it:

```
// use brackets to force evaluation order
($o->foo)(args..);
// use dedicated function
call_user_func($o->foo, args..);
// use two steps
$foo = $o->foo;
$foo(args..);
```

I'd try the first variant first, but I'm not sure if PHP allows it. The last variant is the most cludgy, but that one surely works.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you can't define class methods outside the class itself. So, you can't create an instance of stdClass and then dynamically create methods for it.