# Is it possible to store a function in PHP object's properties?

Tags: php

Is it possible to store a function in PHP object's properties like this:

```
class testing {
    public $testvars;
    function __construct(){
        $this->testvars = function(){
            return "Test String";
        };
    }
}
```

If it's possible, how do you call it?

I have been trying to call it like this:

```
$main = new testing();
$main->testvars();
```

But it throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method testing::testvars()
```

Comment: check out this answer it has all the details you need
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly

Comment: try this - $obj = new testing();
echo call_user_func($obj->testvars);

Comment: thank you Klemen, that link is helpful..

Comment: `$main->testvars->__invoke();`

Answer (score 2):

Try to call like

```
$this->testvars();
```

Considering that you are calling this function in the same class.And if you are calling this in another class you need to add this `_call()` function

```
public function __call($method, $args) {
   if(isset($this->$method) && is_callable($this->$method)) {
       return call_user_func_array(
           $this->$method, 
           $args
       );
   }
}
```

to your new class and you can call it as

```
$main->testvars();
```

Comment: how could it be possible outside the class?

Comment: thank you Gautam3164, it work like a charm..

Comment: @Forkiki good question too :-)

Comment: Question is why to store a closure if you wan't to access it afterwards like a real method of the class instance. Why not just write out the method then?

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER nice point but we don't know why the OP needed it.And yes your point is good thing if she need it like you said

Comment: I actually want to create a framework with different writing methods, for example, there is an assumption like "if($condition) {return true;}", I want to change it into "$Class->if($condition); $Class->returnif();", the problem is we cannot create a function with the name "if()", that's why I have to generate a function with the name "if()" via a property name

Answer (score 1):

You have to call your closure using [`call_user_func()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func.php) or [`call_user_func_array()`](http://ch2.php.net/manual/de/function.call-user-func-array.php).

So you can do the following:

```
$testing = new testing();
echo call_user_func($testing->testvars);
```

To call your closure outside of the class itself.

Comment: I run PHP 5.5 and still got the same error.

Comment: thank you TiMESPLiNTER, i appreciate your answer..

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is: **yes**, PHP syntax has lack of support fur such situation. Neither `{..}` nor `(..)` may help you. The only way to access the property (without `__call()` magic) is:

```
class testing {
    public $testvars;
    function __construct(){
        $this->testvars = function(){
            return "Test String";
        };
    }
}

$obj = new testing();

echo call_user_func_array($obj->testvars, []);
```

So to pass your callback into [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array). Note big difference with passing of `[$obj, 'testvars']` (which won't work here, obviously) - since your *property* contains a callback, but not *class* contains such method. You may also use [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/call_user_func) of course.

As for syntax support, there is [an RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax) which is proposed by Nikita Popov and which will allow you to resolve the issue with syntax only - so no additional function calls would be needed (Fortunately, that RFC was accepted and has real chances to be implemented in newer PHP versions).

Comment: this solution works. I never heard of `call_user_func()` before. Thank you for pointing it out

Comment: So PHP searches only for valid member methods from object context instead of callables? +1 for the answer

Comment: The answer depends of what are you meaning with "searches". With `->` syntax? Yes. It's method de-reference syntax and PHP will search within current scope for _method_. That, however, may be "tweaked" for arrays, for example, but not for such situation

Comment: Wow. Then why is the same solution needed for static properties. For example if you assign ot `self::$x` a closure. Then PHP should be aware of `Test::$x()` is not a method (to be honest, the error is different - function name must be a string). Shouldn't be all the same as $x() from procedural context?

Comment: No, it is almost same. PHP won't be aware if it's method or property which you're trying to access (because of syntax, yes). Internally, btw, static methods and usual methods are almost same in byte-code, the difference is just flag (sort of).

Comment: The idea behing my comment was that I guess PHP is aware that `$x = function () { };` is callable after `echo $x()` because of the `$` identifier, which is also present in static fields. PHP could mess up the syntax for `$this->property()` because will never search for `property`, but in `self::$property()` it's pretty clear you are trying to access a property which is assigned to callable, isn't it? And the error is different, not that you are trying to access undefined function/method, but that function must be a string

Comment: No, for PHP, `self::$property()` is an attempt to access static method with name "$property" (rule for parsing static calls). Since in _current_ context your `$property` isn't defined, it's empty and you see that error.

Comment: Nice to know that, thank you. I was really confused about it. For `$obj->property()` I am OK for this, because a normal human being will also confuse whether it's a method or property, but for `Class::$property()` it should be very clear, too bad it's not for the current PHP parser.

Comment: There are many mysterious things inside PHP parser. Once you'll open that can of magic, you'll never forget.