# PHP: Object properties can be assigned functions, but then those can't be invoked?

Tags: php, lambda

**Reproduced with this code**

```
<?php
$justReturn1 = function() { return 1;};

class A {
        public $f;
        public function __construct($func) {
                $this->f = $func;
        }
}

$instance = new A($justReturn1); // Create instance

$f = $instance->f; // Assign the function within $instance->f to a variable external to object

echo $f(); // Returns: 1
echo $instance->f(); // Returns: Fatal error: Call to undefined method A::f()
```

The same function can be invoked if I assign it to a variable, but can't be invoked if I assign it to an object property.

This is really annoying, since I was counting on this consistency (common sense).

I'm writing a class that receives a big configuration array with some validation functions inside it. I then store those validation functions on an object just fine, but I need an indirection step (creating a variable and assigning this function to it) before I can invoke them!

Is there a flaw in my test? Is this actually PHP unimplementedness?

Comment: It's possible with `call_user_func($instance->f)` or defining `__call()`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535330/calling-closure-assigned-to-object-property-directly  I had to dig a little to come up with a comparable question, but I figured we must have had one. It's an interesting problem and use case.

Comment: Whoops. Thanks for pointing out the duplication. I still think there's value in the question existing; after all, I couldn't find this other question myself.

Comment: Linking it as a duplicate won't cause it to be removed - rather it will remain as a signpost to the existing one. The other wasn't easy to find, and yours will make it a little easier