# How do you use an anonymous function inside a class in PHP?

Tags: php, anonymous-function

How do I call `$greet` inside this class?  I am using PHP 5.5.4.

```
<?PHP   
class Model
{
    public $greet = function($name)
    {
        printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
    };
}

$test = new Model();
$test->greet('World');
$test->greet('PHP');
?>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$greet' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)
```

Also tried this,

```
$test = new Model();
call_user_func($test->greet('World'));
call_user_func($test->greet('PHP'))
```

The anonymous function works fine outside the class (straight from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)).

```
<?php
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};

$greet('World');
$greet('PHP');
?>
```

EDIT:  I took out the dollar signs, in my call (I caught it just as an answer started to roll in.  It did not help,

```
call_user_func($test->greet('World'));
call_user_func($test->greet('PHP'));
```

EDIT:

```
class Model
{
    public $greet;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->greet = function($name)
        {
            printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
        };
    }
}

$test = new Model();
$test->greet('johnny');
```

Now I get,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Model::greet()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact that you call `greet` makes PHP treat it like a function and not a property. You can have the same name for both a property and method in PHP, so the distinction is relevant.

### PHP 7+

In PHP7 the `__call()` method is no longer needed to call closures bound to properties, because of [Uniform Variable Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/uniform_variable_syntax). This will allow you to add parentheses around any code, just like you do in arithmetics.

```
class Model
{
    public $greet;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->greet = function($name)
        {
            printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
        };
    }
}

$test = new Model();
($test->greet)('johnny');
```

### PHP 5

What you can doe as a workaround is use the `__call()` magic method. It will catch the call to the undefined `greet` method.

```
class Model
{
    public $greet;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->greet = function($name)
        {
            printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
        };
    }

    function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (isset($this->$method) && $this->$method instanceof \Closure) {
            return call_user_func_array($this->$method, $args);
        }

        trigger_error("Call to undefined method " . get_called_class() . '::' . $method, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}

$test = new Model();
$test->greet('johnny');
```

Comment: Why do you have to assign the function in a constructor or some other method?  It won't work if you don't (for me).

Comment: You mean the `Parse error` from your first example? Using the `function` keyword in the class definition means creating a method, not an anonymous function.

Comment: No, I mean when you assign the anonymous function to the variable.  It has to be done in a function (or the constructor).  It can't simply be a member variable.

Comment: @johnny It's a 2 stage thing. The PHP code is first interpreted (by the [Zend engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Engine)) and than executed. The class definition (with methods and properties) is handled by the interpreter, while creating objects, anonymous functions, etc is done when the code is executed.

Comment: @johnny In PHP7 the `__call` method will no longer be needed. PHP7 is in alpha right now. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot initialize object variables with the results of expressions. Only static/constant values are allowed. e.g.

```
class foo {
   public $bar = 1+1; // illegal - cannot use an expression
   public $baz = 2; // valid. '2' is a constant
}
```

You'd have to do:

```
class foo {
   public $bar;
   function __construct() {
        $this->bar = function() { .... }
   }
}
```

And to actually invoke the closure, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14063179):

```
$x = new foo()
$x->bar->__invoke();
```

Comment: How do I call it outside the Class?  Do I have to wrap it in another function that returns the value like any old variable usually does?  I tried various ways but they do not work.

Comment: if you build the closure in the constructor, `$bar` will be "pointing" at the closure by the time the `new` call returns. so `$x = new foo(); $x->bar();` should work as expected.

Comment: Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong in my Edit above?  Edit:  Sorry.  I forgot to put in the edit!

Comment: Thanks.  That seems like a lot of trouble for this, so maybe I need to rethink using it.  It looks a lot different in Javascript, for example.

Comment: yeah, well, .... welcome to php. where consistency doesn't matter and everything's made up.

Comment: If you can edit your answer to put in that link, I can mark it answered.  I appreciate all the help.